# DBContext, EF6 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm dealing with a weird problem. Everything works fine locally (VS 2017 IISexpress, MySQL Server **5.7.20**, EF6 and Automatic Migrations Enabled = true).

I've started a MySQL Server on AWS (Server version **5.6.37**) and it gives me the error "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes".

It's driving me crazy. Don't know what to do anymore. Any help?

Context:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public AuthContext()
        : base("AuthContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemCarteira> ItensCarteira { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more research I was able to solve. The resizing for the 3 fields did the job. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659107/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-aspnet-identity-mysql)